ffmpeg: Start/stop recording a stream on black blue screens
I have about a hundred VHS tapes I'm trying to digitize. I've got a capture card hooked up to the VCR so I can play the tapes and record using ffmpeg using /dev/video0 as input, but I have to start/stop the recording manually. The VCR outputs a solid blue screen when it's not playing content.
I'd like to script a way to delay starting the recording while the screen is blue and stop it when it returns, so I can put tapes in one by one and let them play out without worrying about how long each tape is. I'm okay with some buffer to clean up later, but this will be recording over several days, so I don't want to record everything to one huge file. Ideally, I'd end up with one file for each tape.
So far, I've tried finding some way to use -vf signalstats to output color information, so I can trigger a signal to stop ffmpeg and start another. I've also tried to find some way to periodically write frames to an image file that another process can check.
